# How to make a table with variable rows

Tags: tables

This is my code extracted from a custom class file.

```
\makeatletter
\let\@tmemi\@empty\let\@tmemii\@empty
\def\tmemi#1{\gdef\@tmemi{#1}}                   
\def\tmemii#1{\gdef\@tmemii{#1}}

\newcommand{\tablex}{%
\begin{tabular}{r@{ : }ll}
Paticipant         & John Doe  &   Mr.      \\[1ex]
Consultant         & A. Prof   &   PhD      \\[1ex]
\ifx\@tmemi\empty  &           &
\else Team         & \@tmemi   & Manager\fi \\[1ex] 
\ifx\@tmemii\empty &           &
\else              & \@tmemii  & Oganizer\fi
\end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

% Case 1
\tmemi{B. Member}
\tmemii{C. Member}
\tablex

% Case 2
\tmemi{}
\tmemii{}
\tablex
```

and my result and question are shown in the image below (to simplify, I only show member parameters.)

[image]

Comment: Do you still want the two rows of space, just the colons removed?

Comment: Please always post complete documents, not just fragments.

Comment: To both Werner and David: Actually, no phantom blank rows, making it shorter in length. The way I coded leads to ambiguity -- my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after

```
{r@{ : }ll}
```

The `:` is attached to the first column so to make a cell without the `:` you need

```
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}&&
```

so that the first cell uses `r` rather than `r@{ : }`

---

If you want to omit the entire row in the empty cases then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\let\@tmemi\@empty\let\@tmemii\@empty
\def\tmemi#1{\gdef\@tmemi{#1}}                   
\def\tmemii#1{\gdef\@tmemii{#1}}

\newcommand{\tablex}{%
\begin{tabular}{r@{ : }ll}
Paticipant         & John Doe  &   Mr.      \\[1ex]
Consultant         & A. Prof   &   PhD   
\ifx\@tmemi\empty\expandafter\@gobble
\else\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{\\[1ex] Team         & \@tmemi   & Manager}
\ifx\@tmemii\empty\expandafter\@gobble
\else\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{\\[1ex]         & \@tmemii  & Oganizer}
\end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

% Case 1
\tmemi{B. Member}
\tmemii{C. Member}
\tablex

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

% Case 2
\tmemi{}
\tmemii{}
\tablex

\end{document}
```

Comment: much better. But do you have an idea how to not write a row at all. Still getting blank "phantom" rows.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi oh you don't want the vertical space? that wasn't clear, in that case just include the `\\ ` in the conditional part

Comment: @LaRiFaRi see update

Answer (score 2):

The following compartmentalizes the output to manage the portions a bit better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@printtmemi}{Team & \@tmemi  & Manager}
\newcommand{\@printtmemii}{    & \@tmemii & Organizer}
\newcommand{\@nextline}{\\[1ex]}
\def\@emptytmem{}
\let\@tmemi\@emptytmem\let\@tmemii\@emptytmem
\def\tmemi#1{\gdef\@tmemi{#1}}                   
\def\tmemii#1{\gdef\@tmemii{#1}}

\newcommand{\tablex}{%
  \begin{tabular}{r@{ : }ll}
    Paticipant             & John Doe  &   Mr.  \@nextline
    Consultant             & A.\ Prof  &   PhD      
    \setbox8=\hbox{\@tmemi}\ifdim\wd8>\z@%
      \@nextline\@printtmemi\fi
    \setbox8=\hbox{\@tmemii}\ifdim\wd8>\z@%
      \@nextline\@printtmemii\fi
  \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Case 1
\tmemi{B.\ Member}
\tmemii{C.\ Member}
\tablex

\bigskip

% Case 2
\tmemi{}
\tmemii{}
\tablex

\bigskip

% Case 3
\tmemi{D.\ Member}
\tmemii{}
\tablex

\end{document}
```